# Ubuntu 18 resets "Join Displays" display mode after unlocking computer

Tags: 18.04, display

I use two monitors. And I've set "Join Displays" in Display Settings for my Ubuntu 18. And it works fine, until I lock my computer. When, I login again the second display is not showing anything and display mode changed "Single Display". How to solve it?